# How to make a list of specific pairwise comparisons into a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am looking for help on how to make two matrices from one matrix of specific pairwise comparisons (a 210x4 matrix into two 21x21 double matrices).

I have a series of populations, and have made all possible pairwise comparisons for two variables.  I am looking to make two matrices containing the results from the two comparisons, with the population names listed in a particular order.

My data is as follows:

> ```
>  Pop1      Pop2      MSa      MSw
>  pop314      pop1001      0.142773893      0.413771712
>  pop314      pop311      0.722622378      0.771592129
>  pop314      pop803      1.208258657      0.457184787
>  pop314      popLaVall      0.278680371      0.426460114
>  pop314      pop313      1.501337793      0.57032967
>  pop314      pop195      4.736120401      0.627472527
>  pop314      pop317      21.85550936      0.346760222
>  pop314      pop1031      6.335913362      0.500113647
>  pop314      pop252      1.802985027      0.559383559
>  pop314      pop254a      0.431497976      0.678803419
>  pop314      pop1026      0.076486014      0.600192308
>  pop314      popClapier      5.76474359      0.467032967
>  pop314      pop315      0.957616397      0.492037787
>  pop314      pop316      1.295657568      0.560735418
>  pop314      pop925      0.003205128      0.64475052
>  pop314      pop310      5.157311157      0.583150183
>  pop314      pop1313      1.811687687      0.711513323
>  pop314      pop145      2.831497976      0.612136752
>  pop314      pop143      2.716180371      0.632478632
>  pop314      popFreaux      2.12350363      0.78049021
>  pop1001      pop311      2.401578947      0.699247312
>  pop1001      pop803      0.604514089      0.407975911
>  pop1001      popLaVall      0.034722222      0.299632353
>  pop1001      pop313      2.816666667      0.380357143
>  pop1001      pop195      7.35      0.423214286
>  pop1001      pop317      34.99822191      0.278501229
>  pop1001      pop1031      12.73486025      0.456225296
>  pop1001      pop252      4.48675655      0.494660004
>  pop1001      pop254a      0.09      0.53744186
>  pop1001      pop1026      0.729166667      0.53277439
>  pop1001      popClapier      5.168918919      0.335714286
>  pop1001      pop315      2.309379217      0.363086771
>  pop1001      pop316      3.61      0.507142857
>  pop1001      pop925      0.150501672      0.512019231
>  pop1001      pop310      9.166666667      0.454365079
>  pop1001      pop1313      4.142156863      0.590214932
>  pop1001      pop145      5.601111111      0.481627907
>  pop1001      pop143      5      0.463235294
>  pop1001      popFreaux      5.222979296      0.713258977
>  pop311      pop803      12.78856521      0.619481522
>  pop311      popLaVall      2.700082418      0.715926966
>  pop311      pop313      0.596470588      0.773253012
>  pop311      pop195      3.843529412      0.787710843
>  pop311      pop317      38.83100386      0.625886978
>  pop311      pop1031      9.937912002      0.62857444
>  pop311      pop252      0.808336784      0.68821662
>  pop311      pop254a      4.32      0.782040816
>  pop311      pop1026      1.012715827      0.709616788
>  pop311      popClapier      18.01076087      0.725333333
>  pop311      pop315      0.142172452      0.727871854
>  pop311      pop316      0.279677419      0.674705882
>  pop311      pop925      1.456005331      0.768271173
>  pop311      pop310      5.043232323      0.748591065
>  pop311      pop1313      0.787997841      0.787113799
>  pop311      pop145      1.92      0.75755102
>  pop311      pop143      1.709010989      0.778426966
>  pop311      popFreaux      1.266286411      0.804930491
>  pop803      popLaVall      0.234271772      0.411605498
>  pop803      pop313      6.304311454      0.447363217
>  pop803      pop195      13.67574003      0.461997363
>  pop803      pop317      83.31531532      0.379370196
>  pop803      pop1031      47.51637337      0.464747356
>  pop803      pop252      18.61408437      0.489638845
>  pop803      pop254a      0.20975157      0.506636946
>  pop803      pop1026      5.901904622      0.512656498
>  pop803      popClapier      4.243688744      0.424536896
>  pop803      pop315      7.048134722      0.433714223
>  pop803      pop316      17.30517726      0.498248578
>  pop803      pop925      1.864870062      0.49553704
>  pop803      pop310      22.43390329      0.46996997
>  pop803      pop1313      13.79355826      0.535141134
>  pop803      pop145      15.3370243      0.481894678
>  pop803      pop143      11.77177177      0.474815725
>  pop803      popFreaux      22.90795131      0.632728648
>  popLaVall      pop313      3.124038462      0.3890625
>  popLaVall      pop195      7.616346154      0.4390625
>  popLaVall      pop317      32.44776262      0.274609168
>  popLaVall      pop1031      12.11845813      0.46105927
>  popLaVall      pop252      4.688077657      0.503311173
>  popLaVall      pop254a      0.007378049      0.558910256
>  popLaVall      pop1026      1.0125      0.543269231
>  popLaVall      popClapier      3.895833333      0.336693548
>  popLaVall      pop315      2.621146617      0.367324561
>  popLaVall      pop316      3.852083333      0.514760638
>  popLaVall      pop925      0.313415751      0.530408654
>  popLaVall      pop310      9.204166667      0.467653509
>  popLaVall      pop1313      4.401323529      0.61205576
>  popLaVall      pop145      5.822012195      0.497371795
>  popLaVall      pop143      5.28125      0.48125
>  popLaVall      popFreaux      5.354151454      0.72914079
>  pop313      pop195      0.8      0.611111111
>  pop313      pop317      7.74519839      0.321501502
>  pop313      pop1031      0.478942882      0.493347826
>  pop313      pop252      0.097608176      0.552358596
>  pop313      pop254a      3.911428571      0.674545455
>  pop313      pop1026      1.608445946      0.594965278
>  pop313      popClapier      12.34074074      0.436
>  pop313      pop315      0.174410163      0.466081871
>  pop313      pop316      0.272222222      0.555113636
>  pop313      pop925      2.064209402      0.637613122
>  pop313      pop310      0.501960784      0.569791667
>  pop313      pop1313      0.045187166      0.710504202
>  pop313      pop145      0.025714286      0.601818182
>  pop313      pop143      0.061538462      0.620833333
>  pop313      popFreaux      0.058155201      0.782298424
>  pop195      pop317      2.757964347      0.348168168
>  pop195      pop1031      0.259335038      0.505347826
>  pop195      pop252      2.212676669      0.569260004
>  pop195      pop254a      9.282857143      0.710909091
>  pop195      pop1026      5.976013514      0.611631944
>  pop195      popClapier      20.4      0.484
>  pop195      pop315      2.077858439      0.510526316
>  pop195      pop316      2.938888889      0.56875
>  pop195      pop925      6.308653846      0.67290724
>  pop195      pop310      0.125490196      0.607291667
>  pop195      pop1313      1.754278075      0.73907563
>  pop195      pop145      0.825714286      0.638181818
>  pop195      pop143      0.553846154      0.670833333
>  pop195      popFreaux      2.062456277      0.795485238
>  pop317      pop1031      15.29997541      0.425215356
>  pop317      pop252      28.11497211      0.447806407
>  pop317      pop254a      44.74985179      0.448792793
>  pop317      pop1026      47.48503144      0.479849167
>  pop317      popClapier      66.64076577      0.299376299
>  pop317      pop315      16.74822191      0.319477372
>  pop317      pop316      34.4482444      0.465370153
>  pop317      pop925      35.58215771      0.431908422
>  pop317      pop310      7.656476148      0.388150863
>  pop317      pop1313      20.22365033      0.500126725
>  pop317      pop145      12.9563034      0.408792793
>  pop317      pop143      8.885262621      0.383677795
>  pop317      popFreaux      29.44327581      0.642853595
>  pop1031      pop252      4.241305461      0.514720542
>  pop1031      pop254a      18.5129097      0.537345936
>  pop1031      pop1026      16.52515329      0.534884952
>  pop1031      popClapier      38.14319904      0.471353108
>  pop1031      pop315      2.439565424      0.4781559
>  pop1031      pop316      7.033822042      0.519910486
>  pop1031      pop925      11.86476107      0.527703696
>  pop1031      pop310      0.024987506      0.506737859
>  pop1031      pop1313      2.338326635      0.559483541
>  pop1031      pop145      0.571029357      0.516476371
>  pop1031      pop143      0.231884058      0.513535685
>  pop1031      popFreaux      4.224632193      0.64002277
>  pop252      pop254a      7.186176046      0.600900701
>  pop252      pop1026      3.351338895      0.578039683
>  pop252      popClapier      22.40441468      0.516890517
>  pop252      pop315      0.047109644      0.525020886
>  pop252      pop316      0.166106116      0.555088371
>  pop252      pop925      3.375603641      0.587313867
>  pop252      pop310      2.418171866      0.560597572
>  pop252      pop1313      0.019713727      0.623775124
>  pop252      pop145      0.495266955      0.572993725
>  pop252      pop143      0.543299176      0.575551433
>  pop252      popFreaux      0.023520042      0.698657062
>  pop254a      pop1026      1.713735955      0.635603448
>  pop254a      popClapier      4.407857143      0.584
>  pop254a      pop315      3.59215311      0.596290727
>  pop254a      pop316      6.08047619      0.595242718
>  pop254a      pop925      0.537624434      0.696711146
>  pop254a      pop310      12.40870748      0.653049645
>  pop254a      pop1313      6.342891326      0.742125903
>  pop254a      pop145      8      0.673333333
>  pop254a      pop143      6.883902439      0.701538462
>  pop254a      popFreaux      8.350843373      0.789142987
>  pop1026      popClapier      12.60570988      0.556170886
>  pop1026      pop315      1.052988269      0.563230994
>  pop1026      pop316      2.334722222      0.576672535
>  pop1026      pop925      0.197542735      0.621776661
>  pop1026      pop310      8.501893939      0.596172481
>  pop1026      pop1313      2.794792917      0.654986213
>  pop1026      pop145      4.338455056      0.608017241
>  pop1026      pop143      3.6125      0.614583333
>  pop1026      popFreaux      4.44001004      0.718804528
>  popClapier      pop315      13.7255117      0.40247678
>  popClapier      pop316      21.03969072      0.525789474
>  popClapier      pop925      7.697898032      0.555581614
>  popClapier      pop310      27.64227642      0.495726496
>  popClapier      pop1313      19.85294118      0.631452581
>  popClapier      pop145      21.5697619      0.524
>  popClapier      pop143      18.54545455      0.516129032
>  popClapier      popFreaux      24.55834337      0.737644455
>  pop315      pop316      0.00215311      0.532311449
>  pop315      pop925      1.514721098      0.568908295
>  pop315      pop310      1.959200326      0.512623021
>  pop315      pop1313      0.091594135      0.639713471
>  pop315      pop145      0.537607656      0.53914787
>  pop315      pop143      0.601503759      0.535885167
>  pop315      popFreaux      0.10506422      0.739733672
>  pop316      pop925      2.53766328      0.583931213
>  pop316      pop310      3.601282051      0.561601307
>  pop316      pop1313      0.231630547      0.61509979
>  pop316      pop145      1.051904762      0.571941748
>  pop316      pop143      1.008333333      0.57393617
>  pop316      popFreaux      0.362070367      0.684715259
>  pop925      pop310      8.012820513      0.627337073
>  pop925      pop1313      3.092477376      0.719310735
>  pop925      pop145      4.506251885      0.647731554
>  pop925      pop143      3.989010989      0.669471154
>  pop925      popFreaux      4.07878621      0.776336475
>  pop310      pop1313      1.656524679      0.683473389
>  pop310      pop145      0.522993197      0.601985816
>  pop310      pop143      0.266666667      0.614035088
>  pop310      popFreaux      2.246668919      0.758309428
>  pop1313      pop145      0.268315055      0.70002064
>  pop1313      pop143      0.338823529      0.727941176
>  pop1313      popFreaux      0.000436134      0.793307244
>  pop145      pop143      0.015609756      0.64
>  pop145      popFreaux      0.380473003      0.766501478
>  pop143      popFreaux      0.438116101      0.786486151
> ```

I would like to make one matrix each containing the MSa (matrix 1) and MSw (matrix 2) data, respectively, with identical column and row names of population names, like the following first four rows/columns for the MSa matrix:

> ```
>              pop314           pop1001          pop311           pop803      ...
>  pop314      0                0.142773893      0.722622378      1.208258657
>  pop1001     0.142773893      0                2.401578947      0.604514089
>  pop311      0.722622378      2.401578947      0                12.78856521
>  pop803      1.208258657      0.604514089      12.78856521      0
>  ...
> ```

Secondly, I would like to make the matrices with the populations in this order (I've made the list of names in this order an R list called "popnames"):

> pop317, pop252, pop254a, pop145, popFreaux, pop803, pop195, pop1001, pop311, pop1026, pop1031, pop310, pop925, pop316, pop315, pop314, pop313, pop130, popClapier, pop1313, popLaVall, pop143

Any help you could provide would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 MSa.tbl <- xtabs( MSa ~ Pop1 + Pop2 , data=dat)
 MSw.tbl <- xtabs( MSw ~ Pop1 + Pop2 , data=dat)
```

These will be table objects which inherit from matrices. Generally contingency tables have integer values but that requirement is not enforced. If you wnated to have "true" R matrices, you could wrap as.matrix around them. (Missing values get coded as 0 as would be expected in a contingency table. If you want those entries to be NA then:

```
is.na(MSa.tbl) <- MSa.tbl==0
```

There are two formats for such data: "long" as you offered (and is preferred by databases and most of the plotting functions in R) or "wide" as is needed for compact displays and functions like `image` that expect a matrix layout. There is an `as.data.frame.table` function that goes "backward" from a table object to the long dataframe representation.

Comment: Hmm, I tried the above with the command: MSa.tbl <- xtabs( MSa ~ Pop1 + Pop2 , data=dat) and I got the following error: Error in Summary.factor(22L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  sum not meaningful for factors

Comment: You must have made an error in your data input that caused MSa to be a factor variable. I checked the code on your dataset above and it worked fine. If there is a single character value in the MSa column it can invisibly cause the whole column to be a factor. You should use colClasses when using read.table or read.csv to be safe and now you need to use: `dat$MSa<-as.numeric(as.character(dat$MSa))` to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't give me the results I need, but thanks for your help! I will edit the question to be more clear.